# Receiving Files from post - PHP

Tags: php, laravel, post

I'm building an app that receives posts with binary files via api from different apps. My app is built on PHP-Laravel. The app is receiving the post request but I have not been able to get the files from the request to use on the app. One of the problems I think is I am not able to tell what the 'names' of the POST requests are given they are implemented on other apps.

Kindly assist.

Comment: Can you show the code from the form (view) and the controller?

Comment: I don't have a form. I'm sending images from other apps. dicom files

Comment: public function receive(Request $request)
    {
        


        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $serialized=new SerializedRequest;
            $serialized->request='this is the key: '.$key;
            $serialized->save();
        }

    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The image is in the post body so I got it by using the file_get_contents PHP function.

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
```